# Corda user permission not working as expected

Tags: blockchain, corda

Using Corda 4.3 o/s cordapp-example. Ran deploNodes gradle task. I have added another flow com.example.flow2.ExampleFlow2 to test a user2. The user is able to call the flow only when he is given permission to InvokeRpc.startTrackedFlow which is understandable. However, the user is then also able to call com.example.flow.ExampleFlow which should not happen. My security block of the node.conf is given below. Any idea what is going wrong?

```
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                },
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[                    
                        "InvokeRpc.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name",
                        "InvokeRpc.startTrackedFlow",
                        "StartFlow.com.example.flow2.ExampleFlow2"
                    ]
                    user=user2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same observation and opened an issue on Corda repository, they closed the issue (https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/5861) and opened a related JIRA (https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-3577).

Comment: Thanks Adel. Quite recent. Have you tested password encryption (SHIRO_1_CRYPT)? That's next on my list. I completed testing SSL and it works.

Comment: No I havent', I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried it and it works, but that functionality is only for RPC users' passwords, you can't use it for other passwords in `node.conf` like DB password for instance.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Adel.

Comment: @AdelRustum password encryption (SHIRO_1_CRYPT) worked only on windows. It didnt work on RHEL. Any ideas? I am posting a separate question here though.

Comment: It worked for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Turns out that is not the issue. Its the SSL, I am seeing log "Failed to find a store at certificates\sslkeystore.jks". When I disable SSL, password encryption worked. I had given absolute path in keyStorePath.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you solved the issue.

Your permissions look correct and I would have recommended to look at what was happening on the user authentication side as you did. I'm not surprised that it turned out to be an SSL issue.

Thanks for using corda!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Apparently, adding `InvokeRpc.startTrackedFlow` to your RPC user permissions gives "super user" powers, and allows your user to run **all flows**.
If you remove that permission; your flow restrictions will work correctly.

See last few comments on the issue [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/5861).